# не понятно, почему не принимает код

Tags: python, циклы, список

Решаю задачки на codewars:
Вот задание:

```
Given a number n, return the number of positive odd numbers below n, EASY!

Examples (Input -> Output)
7  -> 3 (because odd numbers below 7 are [1, 3, 5])
15 -> 7 (because odd numbers below 15 are [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13])
Expect large Inputs!
```

Вот мой код:

```
def odd_count(n):
    c = []
    for i in range (n):
        if not n%2==0:
            if n > 0:
                c.append(n)       
    return len(c)
```

и выводит:

```
Test Results:
Fixed Tests
Basic Test Cases
15 should equal 7
15023 should equal 7511
Completed in 2.53ms
Completed in 2.57ms
```

Не понятно что не так

Comment: ну, потому что проверять надо i, а не n . и сравнение с 0 нужно убрать, сделайте `for i in range (1, n)`

Comment: Еще: если нужно только число, то нет необходимости создавать список и потом смотреть на его длину. Достаточно сразу считать количество, прибавляя к числу 1 каждый раз.

Comment: И опять еще: в задании даны два примера входных и выходных данных. Это не просто так, это для того, чтобы ты мог проверить свой код до отправки. Если бы ты запустил свой код на этих примерах и сравнил, то понял бы сразу, что у тебя ошибка.

Answer (score 4):

> ```py
>    for i in range (n):
>        if not n%2==0:
>            if n > 0:
>                c.append(n)
> ```

Вам не кажется странным, что вот у вас цикл по переменной `i`, но при этом вы эту переменную `i` **нигде** внутри цикла **не используете**? Вот в этом и ошибка.

Но вообще эта задача, если подумать, решается вообще без циклов:

```py
def odd_count(n):
     return n // 2
```